Topological vector space - sufficient to check continuity for neighborhoods of $0$
I am reading Hormander's Functional Analysis notes. He defined a topological vector space on Page $17$, and then said that since the open sets are invariant under translations, it is sufficient to check the conditions on the neighborhoods of $0$ for continuity:

I am confused. Even if we have checked the four continuity at $0$s, we don't know that our space is a topological vector space. The open sets might not be invariant under translations. How can we conclude that our space is a topological vector space?

We are assuming the topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ is “the usual metric topology”. In this case, it is enough check in neighborhoods of zero.

@Malady could you provide more details? It would be really helpful. I failed to prove that it's enough to check neighborhoods of $0$.

What often occurs in practice when defining topological vector spaces is that a neighbourhood base of $0$ is given. Then you take translates of such sets to obtain a neighbourhood base for each point and consequently a topology on the vector space. Then you verify that the vector space equipped with this topology is a topological vector space. With this topology it turns out verifying those conditions in (2.2.1)', which only require looking at sets involving the neighbourhood base of $0$, imply that this additional topology structure on the vector space makes it into a topological vector space.
Since a neighbourhood base for this topology is defined as translates of a neighbourhood base of $0$, it does not take much work to show that translations are continuous bijective mappings with continuous inverses and are consequently homeomorphisms.
Let $V$ be the underlying vector space over the field $K$. The continuity of the translations can now be used as follows. If $(x_{0}, y_{0})\in V\times V$ then the map $(x,y)\mapsto x + y$ is continuous at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ if and only if
\begin{equation}
(x,y) \mapsto (x + x_{0}) + (y + y_{0}) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
is continuous at $(0,0)$. Then the observation
\begin{equation}
(x + x_{0}) + (y + y_{0}) = (x + y) + (x_{0} + y_{0})
\end{equation}
for $x,y\in V$ implies that (1) is the composition of the map $(x,y)\mapsto x + y$ with the map $z\mapsto z + (x_{0} + y_{0})$. Since translations are continuous and as $(x,y)\mapsto x + y$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ by (2.2.1)', it follows that $(x,y) \mapsto (x + x_{0}) + (y + y_{0})$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ which obtains the desired result. Hence the addition operation is continuous.
You now apply analogous reasoning with the observation
\begin{equation}
(a + a_{0})(x + x_{0}) = ax + ax_{0} + a_{0}x + a_{0}x_{0}
\end{equation}
for $a, a_{0}\in K$ and $x, x_{0} \in V$ combined with the continuity of the addition operation and the other three conditions of (2.2.1)' to show that scalar multiplication is continuous at each $(a_{0}, x_{0})\in K\times V$. Consequently, scalar multiplication is also continuous.
